# facebook is not showing image and video after share using feed dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-sharer, facebook-feed

I am trying to share video link using Facebook share dialog but after sharing the url on Facebook, Facebook does not show the image and also does not play video on the Facebook after sharing it.

I am trying to share links like how YouTube share their videos on Facebook so that user can play the videos on the Facebook after sharing it. Here is my code

```
FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'share',
        quote: 'share it using facebook',
        mobile_iframe: true,
        href: 'https://example.com/raisingfundsthroughvideo',
        hashtag:'#websitename',
    }
);
```

in my meta tags i have also used the image width and height but still the image is not showing.

```
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg" /> 
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
```

facebook link debugger gives me this error on its page

> Provided og:image,
>   https://d3ekuwxfrjk8w6.cloudfront.net/folder/folder/filename
>   could not be downloaded because it exceeded the maximum allowed sized
>   of 8Mb or your server was too slow to respond.

the above image url is valid and I don't know why it is not showing the image is it because of the Cloudfront url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use cloudfront as well and at least for the thumbnail preview that you see after sharing a URL on the share dialog, I know that it must be an image served from the same website URL and the index.html has this:

```html
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/assets/thumbnail.png"/>
```

And yes, you must comply with the size limits of the thumbnail image.

Update: The URL you provide in "og:image" has to be publicly visible which means that if you copy, paste and visit that URL on a new browser window you should see the thumbnail image.

In this example you would need to have an S3 bucket called `example.com` which has the content of your site and another one `www.example.com` which is empty but is setup for Static Website Hosting which redirects to `example.com`.  Your cloud front needs to have be setup as follows:

- origin: `example.com.s3.amazonaws.com`
- cname: `example.com, *.example.com`  (so that www.example.com works)

Go in your cloudfront distribution and click Edit you will see a place to enter the CNAMEs and enter `example.com  *.example.com` and save the changes.

Click on the Origin tab and setup an origin as follows: 
Origin Domain Name: `example.com.s3.amazonaws.com`
Origin ID: `s3-example`
Origin Type: `S3 Origin`

Then wait until after cloudront re-enables your distribution.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply the images size is 10 to 30 kb max but all of my images are on the  amazon s3 so can you please suggest me how can i add my example.com in the cloudfront url so that facebook picks up my images from cloud front.

Comment: My images are generating dynamically that is why they are stored on amazon s3 can you please suggest a way where i can get facebook to show my images from the s3 when i am sharing them. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I updated my answer with additional info regarding your cloudfront URL.

Comment: can you please give me details on how can i setup my cloudfront to use the above cnames like you have mentioned i am new to amazon so it will be really appreciated sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Updated.  Hope that helps you!  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks let me try it.. :)

Comment: i have setup cdn.example.com to access amazon s3 bucket files and i am using amazon s3 signed urls but it giving me this error on facebook link debugger  'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.

Comment: here is my url 
https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.excideo.com%2Fchallenge-explainer%2Fthumbnail-images%2F434behvm2vew-434o1meckvm8%3FExpires%3D1504940274%26Signature%3DqANw7%7Ek59Nlll-iBEXekXcJakt-kMjhBg8ZWwAF6IhE1QJckVqSHoL7Fp7DWJmRaDyVvhh-42CP3sVRAalVS%7E4AEtLtcJoqi1Uh%7E2Wqp8-taqHi0pawRS0I9AD2SpDId37nfmNAqVy5tWFi0O0uJSdgEvdz8q6wl%7Eb8FWVtIoX0al37gzAW8TuJC9viatZ9ez6qzh0Hg12Q1Mol7nUe1kvCL4opEPZflNNXP5rdEKL9JbK3G5NJo4vVQIp0ONGnJF0EiH5YAQkQHyp%7EdiZLil899Z1PNiAz%7Ebm6VP%7E09eTvco9TyVivUJDDqeGTnykNg3G7p%7E2zZ-RdBLi3ZrrdnDQ__%26Key-Pair-Id%3DAPKAI33C6BDMY4E5KYJA

Comment: That URL has encoded asciii characters and facebook wants the real un-escaped URL.   See : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp   in other words the more readable url version which would end up looking something like this: 

`http://example.com/assets/thumbnail.png`